# Do Not Filter vs Ignore Invalid Geometries

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, analysis, invalid-data

In QGIS 3, What's the difference between "Do not filter (better performance)" and "Ignore invalid geometries"?

Both can be found at Settings > Options > Processing > General

Both are options to ignore invalid geometries during spatial analysis.

Comment: Read it literally. "Do not filter" disables filtering, thus also invalid geometries are forwarded to processing.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the info. so what happens to invalid geometries if they are still forwarded to processing? could that lead to some errors?

Comment: I would guess that it depends on what algorithm is the next on the row and how sensitive it is.

Answer (score 1):

"Ignore invalid geometries" is poorly worded -- this option should be "Skip features with invalid geometries". Selecting it causes those features to be skipped over, just like they don't exist.